# Printing strings from an array in a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

I keep getting a crash in the case 4 of my switch in my main function and cant fix it.

I will explain the code a bit and hope you guys can help me:

Initializing the function

```
void function1(char[]);
```

Declaring the array of strings

```
const char *my_array[] = {
"Array of strings one",
"Array of strings two",
"Array of strings three"};
```

Looping through the array of strings in the main function (This works correctly, it prints the array of strings)

```
int i;
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
}
```

The code in the switch function (still in the main function)

```
case 4:
            function1(my_array);
            break;
```

I've tested and all of the previous code works correctly, the problem is in here (outside the main function):

```
void function1(char my_array[]) {
for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
}
printf("\n");}
```

When I execute the case 4 of the switch, it crashes.

The 2 warning the log gives:

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'function1' from incompatible pointer
> type
>
> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2
> has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

Sorry if the explanation its a bit unclear I tried as hard as I could for it to be easy to understand.

I really hope you guys can help me, thanks!!

Comment: You're not passing a `char []`, you're passing a `char *[]` or `char **`

Answer (score 9):

The first warning, namely

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'function1' from incompatible pointer type

tells the story: you are passing an array of character pointers, but the function declaration says that it wants a simple character pointer.

The second warning tells you the same thing from the inside of the function:

> warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int' [-Wformat=]

The format wants a C string, but you are passing a single `char`<sup>*</sup>.

All you need to do to fix this is to add a missing asterisk to the declaration of `function1`:

```
void function1(const char *my_array[])
//             ^^^^^      ^
```

While you are at it, add `const` to match the declaration of `my_array` in `main`.

<sup>*</sup>Compiler says that you are passing an `int`, not `char`, because `printf` takes variable number of parameters, so the compiler applies certain transformations to function's arguments. One of such transformations is promotion of all `char`s to `int`s.

Comment: It should be `void function1(const char *my_array[])` to match the declaration of the `my_array` variable in main.

Comment: @mch You are right, OP should add `const` as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Please have a closer look at the function deceleration

> void function1(char my_array[])

You are passing in char array which is string (which obviously you do not want). The second problem is with this line,

```
printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
```

when you say my_array[i], you are trying to access a **character** at 'i' position and using %s to print a character (which is a crash). To print a character you should write this

```
printf(%c\n", my_array[i]);
```

Now lets fix the code according to your requirement, you should have a function which takes the array of char pointer (OR string)

```
void function1(const char* my_array[])
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Please notice the use of 'const' (if you just have to read/print the data from your string array). Please consider sending the size of array too and use that size to iterate through your loop.

```
void function1(const char* my_array[], size_t n)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I've tried all your solutions and when I add "const" in the function it gives me an error "error in conflicting types".

Reading all of you I figured out that I was passing only a character in the function not a string of characters (the * was missing in the initialize of the function and the function).

I changed this:

```
void function1(char[]);
```

To this:

```
void function1(char*[]);
```

and this:

```
    void function1(char my_array[]) {
    for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

to this:

```
    void function1(char* my_array[]) {
    for (i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    printf("%s\n", my_array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

And it works like a charm!

Sorry if it was a bit of a noob question but i'm starting with C programming.

Thank you all for your answers I appreciate it!

Comment: :) Good to hear! Keep it up!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want a function which loops through the elements of an array and prints all its contents, here's what I suggest:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void view(char *array[]){
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array)/sizeof(char); i++){ 
        //sizeof(array)/sizeof(char) = length of any array          
        printf("\nElement -> %s",array[i]);
    }
}


int main() {

    char *arr[] = {"String One", "String Two", "String Three"};

    view(arr); //Calling the function

    return 0;
}
```